# Streamlit Panda Query Function Syntax Error When Finding Column in CSV Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, streamlit

When Using Streamlit to build a data interface getting a syntax error.  My downloaded csv dataframe has a column 'NUMBER OF PERSONS INJURED', after converting it into a dataframe with panda and trying to use the query function to reference it I'm getting errors like below.  I converted the text to lower case in the dataframe.  I've attached the error message and sample csv file screenshot.  Github has code and sample csv file.  My questions are:

**1.** how to fix this error?  **2.** What's the underlying cause of it?

Code in Question:

```
injured_people = st.slider("", 0, 19)
st.map(data.query("number of persons injured > @injured_people")[["latitude", "longitude"]].dropna(how="any"))
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjJeU.jpg)

[csv sample shot of number of persons injured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMP0A.jpg)

Things I've tried:

- adding `''` to number of persons injured to convert to `string`.  But
  then get error about st.slider being `int` and unable to operate with
  `>` between str & int.
- hacking the csv by converting number of persons injured with
  underscore `number_of_persons_injured` but that throws undefined
  error.
- Converting @injured_people to a string. Yes stupid I know.  String() undefined error.

  > injured_people = st.slider("", 0, 19)
  >
  > injured_people = string(injured_people)

Git File: https://github.com/petersun825/Bike_Crash_Dashboard_NYC/blob/master/app.py

Answer (score 0):

pandas does not know what you mean for the column name with spaces, which leads it to try and find a column `number`. You can escape the spaces with backticks:

```py
st.map(data.query("`number of persons injured` > @injured_people")[["latitude", "longitude"]].dropna(how="any"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by edit the column name to something simpler, like injured_person. Then restart your device and try run the streamlit again

Answer (score 0):

```
st.map(data.query("injured_persons >= @injured_people")[["latitude", "longitude"]].dropna(how="any"))
```

This might help you, change the number_of_persons_injured to injured_persons in CSV and Your Python Code

Else try with changing NUMBER OF PERSONS INJURED in CSV instead of spaces between add underscore that might work `number_of_persons_injured`